# Generating a CSRF token manually with Flask WTF-Forms

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms, csrf-protection

I'd like to create and fill out a Flask WTF-Form using only python code.  However, the form doesn't automatically generate a CSRF token when I create it with python code.  Is there any way to do this manually?

The form in question:

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, URL

class URLForm(Form):
    url = StringField('url', validators=[DataRequired(), URL(), Level3Url()])
```

the code I use to generate the form:

```
from forms import URLForm
form = URLForm()
if 'url' in request.args:
    url = request.args.get('url')
    form.url.data = url
    if form.validate():
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be effectively disabling CSRF protection by generating and passing a token to the form locally. It's only effective when the user submits a previously generated token.

Since you're not using CSRF protection, disable it. You can also pass `request.args` as the source of data.

```
form = URLForm(request.args, csrf_enabled=False)
```

If you want to use CSRF for this form, then the form needs to send the `csrf_token` field, which can be rendered with `{{ form.csrf_token }}` or `{{ form.hidden_tag() }}`.

Answer (score 0):

In newest version of **flask_wtf (0.14.2)**  you can disable csrf token in this way.

```
form = URLForm(request.args, meta={'csrf': False})
```