# Obtain CSRF-Token and assign to variable

Tags: python, flask, csrf, flask-wtforms

I want to obtain csrf-token provided by `flask-wtf` and assign it to a variable for future use with my flask app architecture. There's a way to either render it with hidden field `{{ form.csrf_token }}` or via `csrf_token()` for jinja. But docs do not mention how to achieve, say, the following:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'secret'
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)


@app.route('/api/get/endpoint_which_returns_json/', methods=['GET'])
def api():
    csrf_token = # ??? what belongs here ???
    return jsonify({'token': csrf_token})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

How to achieve that? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `{{ form.csrf_token }}` or `{{ csrf_token() }}` in your templates through Flask-WTF, they are just calling the `flask_wtf.csrf.generate_csrf()` function. You can import that and call it yourself to generate a token inside your view:

```py
from flask_wtf.csrf import generate_csrf

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def api():
    return jsonify({'token': generate_csrf()})
```

I'm assuming the idea here is that the api client would be responsible for returning the token with POST requests to your other api resources? If you are just generating the token server-side so as to be able to validate forms that would otherwise require it, [you may as well just disable CSRF protection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38231773/6560549).

Comment: This part of calling the function is completely missing from the official documentation unfortunately